# Action Script 3.0 Vector not storing variables after Function exits

Tags: flash, actionscript, vector, scope

I am new to Action Script , i Have worked before with OOP languages but i am facing a problem , I have to build a brochure Application for a library , they handed me the data of their books in a XML format . I built two classes :Book and Library.

**Book.as:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;    
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite
    public class Book extends Sprite
    {
        public var _author_name:String;
        public var _book_title:String;
        public var _book_subject:String;
        public var _book_edition:String;
        public var _ISBN: String;
        public var _publication_year:String;
        public var _price:String;
        public var _in_stock:String;
        public var _book_cover:String;
        public function Book()
        {
        }
        public function  getAuthorName():String
        {
            return _author_name;
        }
        public function  getBookTitle():String
        {
            return _book_title;
        }
        public function  getBookSubject():String
        {
            return _book_subject;
        }
        public function  getBookEdition():String
        {
            return _book_edition;
        }
        public function  getISBN():String 
        {
            return _ISBN;
        }
        public function  getPublicationYear():String
        {
            return _publication_year;
        }
        public function  getPrice():String
        {
            return _price;
        }
        public function  getAvailability():String
        {
            return _in_stock;
        }
        public function getBookCover():String
        {
            return _book_cover;
        }
        public function setBookCover(temp:String):void
        {
            _book_cover = temp;
        }
        public function  setAvailability(temp:String):void
        {
            _in_stock = temp;
        }
        public function  setPrice(temp:String):void
        {
            _price = temp;
        }
        public function  setPublicationYear(temp:String):void
        {
            _publication_year = temp;
        }
        public function setISBN(temp:String):void
        {
            _ISBN = temp;
        }
        public function setBookEdition(temp:String):void
        {
            _book_edition = temp;
        }
        public function setBookSubject(temp:String):void
        {
            _book_subject = temp;
        }
        public function setBookTitle(temp:String):void
        {
            _book_title = temp;
        }
        public function setAuthorName(temp:String):void
        {
            _author_name = temp;
        }
        public override function toString():String
        {
            var book_desc:String;
            book_desc = "Author Name: " + _author_name + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Title: " + _book_title + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Subject: " +_book_subject + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Edition : " +_book_edition + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "ISBN: " +_ISBN + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Publication Year: " + _publication_year + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Price: " + _price + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Available: " +_in_stock + "\n";
            book_desc = book_desc + "Book Cover URL : " +_book_cover + "\n";  
            return book_desc;
        }
        public function equals(temp:Book):Boolean
        {
            if(_ISBN == temp.getISBN())
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

**Library.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;    
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Sprite

    public class Library extends Sprite
    {
        public var xml:XML;
        public var url_loader:URLLoader;
        public var _book_vector:Vector.<Book>
        public var _xml_path:String;
        public function Library(xml_path:String)
        {
            _xml_path = xml_path;
            _book_vector = new Vector.<Book>(20);
        }
        public function getXMLPath():String
        {
            return _xml_path;
        }
        public function setXMLPath(temp:String):void
        {
            _xml_path = temp;
        }
        public function LoadXML():void
        {
            url_loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(_xml_path));
            url_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,ParseXML);
        }
        public function ParseXML(temp:Event):void
        {
            xml = new XML(temp.target.data);
            LoadBooks();
        }
        public function LoadBooks():void
        {
            for(var i :int=0;i<xml.children().length();i++ )
            {
                _book_vector[i] = new Book();
                _book_vector[i]._author_name = xml.children()[i].AuthorName;
                _book_vector[i]._book_title =  xml.children()[i].BookTitle;
                _book_vector[i]._book_subject = xml.children()[i].Subject;
                _book_vector[i]._book_edition = xml.children()[i].Edition;
                _book_vector[i]._price = xml.children()[i].Price;
                _book_vector[i]._publication_year = xml.children()[i].Year;
                _book_vector[i]._in_stock = xml.children()[i].Availabilty;
                _book_vector[i]._book_cover = xml.children()[i].ImagePath;
                _book_vector[i]._ISBN = xml.children()[i].@ISBN;
            }
        }
        public function printLibrary():void
        {
            for(var i:int=0;i<this._book_vector.length;i++)
            {
                trace(_book_vector[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XML Loads fine , but when i try to call printLibrary() it throes a : Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

when i use the debugger i can see that _book_vector is being loaded with "Books" and filed with data form the XML read , but when LoadBooks exits the vector holds them no more , why ? _book_vector is not local to the function!  what have i Done wrong ? is there something i am not getting correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new Vector.<Book>(20);
```

instead of

```
new Vector().<Book>(20);
```

Using `new Vector()...` gives me this error:

```
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
```

But that's perhaps because my error handler is a little more strict.

Comment: Thank You Arno , I did change it and it's still the same Error #1009 .

Comment: Well for me specifically it is this : TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Library/printLibrary()
 at run_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: In that case you probably call "printLibrary" before "LoadBooks" is called. Since I can't check that with the code you provided I'm not 100% sure, but as fare as I can see the code you posted is correct. You could add some traces here and there to see in which order the methods are called.

Comment: i created an fla file and in Frame action i wrote the following :`code` import Book;
import Library;

var path:String = "year.xml";
var lib:Library = new Library(path);
lib.LoadXML();
lib.printLibrary();

Comment: Ah, that's not gonna work ;) The loading of the xml takes a while (even if it's just a few ms) and the code doesn't hold or stop executing during the load so the printLibrary is executed immediately after the start of the load but before the load is actually finished (that's why you need the Event.COMPLETE handler). So you should call the `printLibrary();` after you called the `LoadBooks();`

Comment: I understand your point about the XML being too slow to load and the fact that the code doesn't stop ,so i am accessing printLibrary() while LoadBooks() hasn't returned yet i.e:COMPLETE but i can't see the work around ?

Comment: If i call printLibrary() after LoadBooks() inside the function ParseXML() it will work ...as i understand by now that XML loading is Asynchronous , so the idea of "some time" is not known , but in this case what should a person do if you want a function to return your vector of Books ?

Comment: there are a couple of ways to tackle this, but it totally depends on how you structure the rest of your code, so an example won't work here but this is what you could do:
- Have the Library class dispatch an event when the books are loaded and listen somewhere else in your app to that event before making any calls like printLibrary to the Library.
- A better way would probably be to load the xml somewhere else in your app (not in the Library) and then pass the loaded data to the Library when you  instantiate it. That way you know that the Library is allways filled with data.

Comment: Thank you Arno , i Understand your point , it's very difficult to grasp it at the beginning specially coming from java , c# ... background i will redesign the hall app from an event perspective . Thank you again :)